# How to display multiple values from =FILTERXML(xml, xpath) function in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, xpath

I am writing `=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml");"//food/name")`, but only the first value is displayed.
It is necessary to use an array but I can not understand how.

> When you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, Excel automatically inserts the formula between { } (a pair of opening and closing braces).

I do this, but the value found is still only the first.

Answer (score 1):

FILTERXML seems to return first match. You can try the [] syntax:

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml");"//food/name[" & ROW() & "]
```

This will display the result in each rows.

Comment: I can navigate through the results if I change the number:
`"breakfast_menu//food[2]//name" `.

But how to display a few?

Comment: I understood! Thanks.

Comment: O365ProPlus automatically develop the result. What's your version of Excel ? Just curious.